# Angular2 - adding [_nghost-xxx-N] and [_ngcontent-xxx-N] messes up my code

Tags: angular, shadow-dom

This is my app.component.html

```
<header>
    <cm-main-navigation></cm-main-navigation>
</header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
    <cm-footer></cm-footer>
</footer>
```

Every page of my app obviously appears after router-outlet.

My css is:

```
:host {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;

    & > * {
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    header,
    router-outlet,
    footer {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
    }

}
```

& > * is supposed to target every page generated by router-outlet, but because of the ngcontent-xxx-N it never gets applied:

```
[_nghost-ray-1] > *[_ngcontent-ray-1] {
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

This is because every page is dynamically generated from the router-outlet, that adds a different prefix every time, and the stylesheet is not updated accordingly.

In fact inspecting my pages root element the css does not appear. Here I got it from the other elements, like header, where it came together with:

```
[_nghost-ray-1] footer[_ngcontent-ray-1], [_nghost-ray-1] header[_ngcontent-ray-1], [_nghost-ray-1] router-outlet[_ngcontent-ray-1] {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

[image: this is css of router-outlet, footer and header]

This was working some Angular 2 version ago, but it stopped working some patches ago.

So my question is, how do I target any children of an host that may change dynamically?
I don't want to change the shadow-dom setting.

No such css appearing here:

[image: There is no such css for the pages]

This to me looks like a bug. That is valid CSS that would normally work, it's Angular 2 breaking it.

This is how it should be:

```
[_nghost-ray-1] > * {
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the `/deep/` special selector.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#-deep-

So :

```
:host /deep/ > * {
    flex: 1 0 auto;    
}
```

Comment: I knew about /deep/, but it should be to styles a children component from the parent, how come it is necessary for dynamically generated content?

I can style a children component ":host element" also from the parent, and I should be able to do so with the "page".

It works, but the logic of how this should be ok still evades me.

Comment: The thing is that the `<router-outlet>` is itself sort of a child component. Your pages are not direct children of your `AppComponent`, they are children of `RouterOutlet`, which makes them unreachable by the parent without a `/deep/` selector.